# Correct use of Section Tag in a Single Page Layout

Tags: html

If this use of tags correct for a single page layout? Or should I use an article tag with a section inside?

```
<div id="page-container">
    <header>
        <h1>Brand Logo</h1>
        <nav>
        </nav> 
    </header>
    <section id="about">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>About Us</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, minus, quidem debitis vel aut libero id consequuntur dicta quasi sapiente.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Services</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis eos asperiores praesentium omnis non veritatis repudiandae fugiat similique possimus id.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor commodi esse assumenda optio impedit ad eaque soluta tempore porro delectus.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>
```

Comment: The second example of the `section` element in the HTML 5.1 specification is a body containing several sections. http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-section-element

Comment: IMHO there's no reason for the `.container divs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

It would create an outline like:

```
1. "Brand Logo"
  1.1 untitled nav
  1.2 "About Us"
  1.3 "Services"
  1.4 "Contact Us"
```

Instead of `section`, `article` may be more appropriate. But you can only decide this if you see the real content. Check its [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-article-element): if it matches your content, use `article`, if not, stay with `section`.